# Best way to connect 2 USB devices to a single port

Tags: usb

I have a 4GB Thumb Drive that the plug broke off.  So I extracted the chip and hard wired it to an old cable to retrieve the data.  Now I'm thinking it might be a fun project.

I have a USB Gravis Eliminator Aftershock game controller that I use to play games, and there is tons of space inside.  I would like to wire the drive inside the controller and have them connect to a single usb port via the cable on the controller.  Does anyone know if I can just solder the wires to the drive pins or do I need some kind of splitter type circuit between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Probably** you can hard wire the 2 power wires to those of the Gravis device but will need to switch the 2 data wires of each device so that only one device at  a time is selected.

If you want a device that allows both devices active at once on the same USB cable you need to add the IC from a passive hub as well. These are cheap and commonly available and it should be a metter of "just doing it. ie cutting and soldering and suitable care mechanically.

The end result may not be very useful compared to just plugging the two devices into an existing passive hub, but you will learn things along the way.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice, Russell. I do have an old 4 port Hub that I don't use anymore since my new computer has 8 ports.  I'll dismantle it and see if there is a clean way to extract the IC.